# Writing Hebrew With LyX

Tags: lyx, hebrew

I am doing my first steps trying to write Hebrew articles with LyX (Or any other solution).
I am using Mac and do not know what to do after I have download LyX.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, but this question is to vague. You have to define some clear problem which we can fix for you. Like this, I can just say: Read http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tutorials and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11 and finally http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew+lyx

Comment: I am looking for the best solution in which I can write in Hebrew

Comment: I would say the first step is to try to compile LyX's Hebrew documents. They are in lib/doc/he/. If you cannot do that, you probably need fonts. I don't know how that works on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Given Macs use unicode by default, your simplest solution is to use XeTeX as the typesetting engine.

See my example at [Two fonts for two languages using lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203078/two-fonts-for-two-languages-using-lyx/203595#203595) which uses Hebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did on Pop!_OS 19.10:

I installed LyX and texlive-full from the repo and [culmus-latex-0.7](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ivritex/files/culmus-latex/)

- In Tools->Preferences->Editing I set it to use keyboard map with null as primary (for English. It works better than american for me) and hebrew as secondary
- In Tools->Preferences->Output->LaTeX->"Use LaTeX font encoding" I enabled it and set it to HE8 (which is an unnecessary step, so skip this)
- In Tools->Preferences->File Formats->"Default Output Formats"->"With TeX Fonts" I set to "PDF (pdflatex)"

In Document->Settings->Fonts:

- I **didn't** use non-TeX fonts (leave it on the default: TeX fonts)
  LaTeX font encoding: "None (no fontenc)"
- I set the Default font to sans serif
- For the Roman, Sans Serif,  Typewriter fonts I set them all to Computer Modern fonts because I found through trial and error that they work, though some others might work too (Latin Modern also appears to work). Math I left on automatic.

Of course I saved all of the changes I made in Document->Settings as Document Defaults.

In order to be able to render my LyX document that I previously created with a different configuration all I had to do was change the fonts and add that line to the preamble.

I also discovered that I need to switch back from Hebrew to English before inserting math to avoid strange artifacts from appearing in the PDF.

I added a version of these instruction to the LyX wiki:
[Hebrew on Linux: Pop!_OS 19.10](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/HebrewOnLinux)