# Can amd 2030e support lyx?

Tags: lyx

I'm looking for a cheap laptop that will support LyX. I found a lenovo v14 82c6006 with CPU amd 3020e. Will it work, and would it be any different?

Hardware SSD and 16GB memory.

Comment: Not sure if your question falls within the scope of this website but when the laptop can run an OS then it will normally also be able to run Lyx.

Comment: What OS will you run? It is true that for macOS, we did see weird changes happen with the underlying changes due to the chip transition. Those are already ironed out for when the LyX 2.4.0 release comes. All this to say that it's not a crazy question; although the mac chip change thing was the only case where I saw something like this happen with respect to LyX.

Comment: I'm planning windows 10. So you're saying it will work exactly the same?

Comment: BTW, it will also support other languages (specifically hebrew)?

Comment: @Ben it appears it can support Hebrew if you use the `xetex` or `xelatex` engines, that comes under the settings somewhere (note: I have never used Lyx before!) https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222755/273733

Comment: @Ben my best guess is that it will, but I have no specific knowledge about that processor.

Comment: No idea of how basic is really the 3020e, but LyX+LaTeX are not 3D games. For years they worked for me in prehistoric CPUs with ridiculously amounts of memory, so  I guess that 16Gb  with any modern CPU for a laptop should be more than enough. If it ran at snail speed with W10, I will try Linux (Debian) installing just what you really need.