# PDF export - Missing \endcsname

Tags: errors, pdftex, culmus

I've Installed yesterday Lyx and MiKTeX on my computer.
I tried to export an example file to see if it is working but I got these LaTex errors (Photo of the errors attatched below):

> **Error 1:**
> *Title:* Missing \endcsname inserted
> *Error Body:*  \newtheorem{theorem}{{\beginR ×ž×©×¤×˜}}[section]
> The control sequence marked  should not appear between \csname
> and \endcsname.

> **Error 2:**
> *Title:* Extra \endcsname
> *Error Body:*  \newtheorem{theorem}{{\beginR ×ž×©×¤×˜}}[section]
> I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

Error 1 repeats 3 times, and error 2 appears after the first error for the first 2 times.

> **Error 3:**
> *Title:* Use of \the doesn't match its definition
> *Error Body:*
> If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always put` 1' after `\a', since control sequence names are made up of letters only.
> The macro here has not been followed by the required stuff, so I'm
> ignoring it.

> **Error 4:**
> *Title:* LaTeX Error: File 'culmus.sty' not found
> *Error Body:*
> ^^M
>
> *** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

[image: Errors]

Comment: If you just started using hebrew isn't a good idea. Learn first to type some english text. And then search a bit to decide if you really want to stick to pdflatex and culmus. That is rather complicated and it need manual installations. An unicode engine like xelatex or lualatex would be easier.

Comment: I agree with @UlrikeFischer and would add that in 2021 it is far better to use `polyglosia` package and compile with XeLaTeX (I am quite sure LyX is capable of doing that) than using `babel` and culmus and things of the sort.

Comment: Also check this answer out https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203595/90297